Why would my PWA install without issue on my desktop, but I am unable to install it on my mobile?
I have a PWA that currently lives in https://unsuitable-price.surge.sh/.
The PWA was made using create-react-app and I generated the service worker using Workbox.
At some point I was able to install the app on my phone (proper install, not "add to homepage") but I changed something and I was not able to ever install it again on any phone. I have always been able to install it on my desktop and that has not changed.
The manifest (shortened for convenience) looks like this:
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/web-manifest-combined.json",
  "short_name": "Clean URLs",
  "description": "Shear off the excess url tracking information and other unnecessary stuff",
  "name": "Clean URLs",
  "icons": [...],
  "screenshots": [...],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  ...
  "share_target": {
    "action": "/",
    "method": "GET",
    "params": {
      "url": "dirtyurl",
      "title": "title",
      "text": "text"
    },
    "enctype": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  "shortcuts": [],
  "orientation": "any"
}

The "Application" tab on the Chrome and Edge dev tools no longer show any installability issues, warnings, or errors.
What I have tried:

Update the icons from one WEBP to many PNG files
Added Screenshots to the web manifest file

The issue persists that the app WILL be installable in Desktop using Chrome or Edge, but it WILL NOT be installed in Mobile. On Mobile, I only ever can add it to the homepage, but not install it. It is important to me to install it because I want to be able to share to the PWA via the OS' share tray.
It is also important to me because I am using this as a learning opportunity.
Thank you all!

but I changed something - can you remember what? have you satisfied these requirements

Oh, I no longer had a 512 px image, only a 192 and smaller. I'll try to add the larger icon and report back.

@JaromandaX I added the 512px icon and pushed the change, but that still didn't let me install on mobile. To respond your earlier question, I mostly changed the icons and the name.

You know there's errors regarding the service worker registration

Oh? No, I am not aware. What error? I am not seeing it.

Oh, I see it now. That SW installation issue was just fixed.
